# Any way to do dummy indenting?

Tags: python, indentation

In other languages, I routinely lay out my code with something like this:

```
//  First part
    something();
    moreStuff();

//  Second Part
    etc();
```

In Python, of course, indenting is interpreted as being part of a (non-existent) block, so I can’t do this.

Is there a trick in Python by which I can fake this? A dummy block or something else?

Comment: Python uses `# to mark a comment` -if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Patrick: While I agree, I think you should put your last comment belongs under mehrdad-pedramfar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53456056/355230) because that is where using a fake `if` block is being suggested (the OP didn't say anything about doing this).

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know about Python’s use of `#` for comments; I was using an example from JavaScript or PHP which are not indent based. I’m not really keen on a dummy `if true:`, though wrapping the code inside a function might do the trick and add more structure at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put an `if True:` at the start of your code block, which would ensure it always runs and would automatically set it at that level of indentation. A lot of scripts run their main code in a block like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

which both makes it more clear that the code is supposed run as a script (rather than as a module) and puts it at that level of indentation you're looking for. If you're working on a bigger program, you're almost always going to be inside a function or a class anyway, so that accounts for some indentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to write like this:

```
#  First part
something();
moreStuff();

#  Second Part
etc();
```

But if you need to have a dummy block, this might help you.

```
if True:
#  First part
    something();
    moreStuff();

#  Second Part
    etc();
```